# Zoom in and out animation words in Textview android

Tags: android, android-animation, textview

I have text and I want to apply zoom in and zoom out animation on words in Textview with background voice.
Like if I have text in Textview and sound for that  "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

then first zoom in and zoom out word "The" **and sound play the Then** "quick" **and sound play the quick** and onward.

I have searched on net but only character by character animation is available. Any help will be appreciated.

**At that time what I have is this:**

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this
fadeIn.setDuration(4000);

SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Red is a new message");
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 4, 0);  
writer.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());        
writer.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);  
writer.startAnimation(fadeIn);
```

it is applying animation on whole text

Comment: please edit your question with your code.

Comment: You could for example use one textView for "The", another textView for "quick" etc... and then animate them one by one. Right now you are animating Alpha values, sounds to me, you are looking for ScaleAnimation